# I18N site: welcome page with links to translated pages, or translatable content type?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I need to create a small web site with a single page that has to be translated into multiple languages. My site is I18N, and Locale + Locale updates enabled.

The page manager allows one to create a landing page and set it as the default page. However, I am not really clear how I could automate the translation of that page. I am considering creating a neutral page with links to translated pages. Something tells me this is not the right way to do it in Drupal.

On the other side, I know I could create a "Welcome" content type, with translation attributes/fields. But then, how do I make sure it would be displayed as the landing page with the correct language? Should I create a landing page with one instance of this content type and translate it?

I am still new to i18n in Drupal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "automate" the translation page but I think you're on the right track for what I think you're trying to accomplish.

1. First make sure you have at least the **Multilingual content** module enabled.
2. You likely want to also go to `admin/config/regional/i18n/strings`
           and make sure that **Filtered HTML** is translatable
3. Then go to `admin/structure/types/manage/page` and then **Publishing options** and choose **Enabled, with translation** under the **Multilingual support** option.

You should now have a basic page that is translatable. There will be a **Translate** option next to the **Edit** option on the node that should allow you to do the translation. Enabling the **Language switcher** as well as translating menus and paths is also recommended.

Comment: By automate, I meant automate the display of the page. I was not clear.

Comment: That should be done by default. If you're on a page and then choose a different language Drupal will pull up the same page in the new language.

Were you planning on having separate subdomains or path prefix or just using browser auto detection?

Comment: No subdomains, just path prefix would be fine. I am still struggling with another issue, but I'll create another question if I can't solve it.

Comment: Well glad you got this one fixed at least!